# Stata multiple level reshape wide to long

Tags: stata, reshape

I'm running into some issues while trying to `reshape` a data set from `long` to `wide`. Here's an example, since I think that explains it best:

Say I wanted to take this `long` data set...

```
|study_id  |event_date |code     |
|--------------------------------|
|1         |09 June 15 |546      |
|1         |09 June 15 |643      |
|2         |23 May 13  |324      |
|2         |12 May 13  |435      |
```

And shape it into a `wide` one like this...

```
|study_id    |event_date_1 |event_date_1_code1 |event_date_1code2| event_date_2   |event_date_2_code1 | event_date_2_code2|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1           |09 June 15   |546                |643              |                |                   |                   |              
|2           |23 May 15    |324                |                 |12 May 13       |435                |                   |
```

What would be the best method of doing this? I imagine I would have to create some sort of `j` variable, but am not certain how to make it so each `event_date` could have multiple `codes`, and each `study_id` multiple `event_date`s.

I already tried doing making a `j` variable and reshaping, using the following code:

```
//Sort by id (just in case)
sort study_id event_date code

//Create j variable
quietly by study_id: gen code_num = cond(_N==1, 1, _n)

//Reshape data
reshape wide event_date code, i(study_id) j(code_num)
```

This, however, did not account for each event_date having multiple potential codes.

I am attempting to convert the data to wide so that I can merge it with another wide data set, and then run analysis over both. An observation in either set is an unique study_id.

Comment: I suggest that you need a really good reason to prefer this data structure. What you have is far more straightforward. Perhaps you can explain what you want to do with it and why it would be better for any purpose.

Comment: I have another data set that contains information on each study_id. I want to use both data sets in an analysis, so I am trying to convert this one to wide, then merge it with my existing wide data set.

Comment: Merging is still possible with this present structure. In neither structure is it obvious what defines an observation. You presumably know, but is it obvious in your question? (You may not be able to see, but two people have posted answers here and then deleted them, and it seems that neither is at all clear on what to recommend to you.)

Comment: I edited my post, let me know what else I can do to help clarify. The other data set is quite large, with ~300 variables, and ideally i'd have all the information in one larger data set.

Comment: What defines an observation? That remains unclear to me.

Comment: In the structures that I wrote, each row is an observation.

Comment: I understand that. I mean logically or substantively, not syntactically.

Comment: In the first table, each observation holds an unique combination of a code and a date. In the second table, each observation holds all of the codes and dates for a single study_id

Comment: Sorry, but I am bailing out at this point as I can't see a way to code that I am sure will really help you.  If you have hundreds of variables already, a structure that increases the number of variables is not obviously  a good idea. Other people may be able to sense what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I would not ever choose to organize my data in the requested fashion, so this should not be taken as support for doing so.

Having said that, something like the following seems to do the trick. The data is similar yours but I'm too lazy to deal with full dates, I just read in the day of the month. I'm posting this as a curiosity, because I've never before seen a need to do `reshape wide` twice in succession.

```
clear
input study_id  date code
1  09  546
1  09  643
2  23  324
2  12  435
end
list
bysort study_id date (code): generate codenum = _n
reshape wide code, i(study_id date) j(codenum)
rename code* code_*_
list
bysort study_id (date): generate eventnum = _n
reshape wide date code_*, i(study_id) j(eventnum)
list
```

Comment: `rename` was revised drastically in Stata 12, so that statement won't work in 10.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I understand that this is not an ideal way of storing the data; is there some other way you would recommend of combining the two data sets that I have? Given that one is long and one is wide. Would it be better to reshape the wide one to long?

Comment: It is almost axiomatic among those who respond to Stata questions both here and on Statalist that, with few exceptions, Stata makes it much more straightforward to accomplish complex analyses using a long organization rather than wide organization of the same data. So my initial reaction would be to not reshape this dataset wide. Without knowledge of your other, wide dataset, I wouldn't venture a guess as to whether that one should be left as is, reshaped long, or summarized in some way before merging with the existing long dataset.